# How to exclude an object from an array in AngularJS filter?

Tags: angularjs, filter

I want to display a list of shops in an unordered list. I want to exclude "currentShop" from all shops. I wrote something like:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-default">
                <li ng-repeat="shop in user.account.shops | filter:!currentShop}">
                    <a href="#/profile">
                        <i class="icon-user"></i> {{shop.name}} </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Try `!'currentShop'`

Comment: I believe you want the `!` in the quotes. Although it depends on what `currentShop` is I suppose. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: @burak is currentShop a object or just string .. name of shop ?

Comment: It's an object @sylwester

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wiTreW?p=preview) you have a working example. You can filter by a `scope` expression

```
ng-repeat="item in list | filter: myExpression"
```

Define your filter function;

```
$scope.myExpression= function(shop) {
  return shop.id !== $scope.current.id;
};
```