# Filter by property of $scope var in a view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular, and I wanted to use scope variable property in the filter statement in the html view like the following:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in allItems | filter:{property: !currentItem.property}">{{item.property}}</li>
```

Here I want to exclude from list of items the item that already displayed: `currentItem`.
But it seems not working for me and I get an empty list.

I was able to implement it by using the filter function:

```
$scope.exceptCurrentItem = function(anItem) {
    return anItem.property != $scope.currentItem.property;
}
```

What I would like to know, why the first approach is not working for me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524021/how-to-exclude-an-object-from-an-array-in-angularjs-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a filter expression you can use a simple ng-if.

I've created a plnkr here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/mlrxoLUoTuwJaKmsW5IU?p=preview

```
<li ng-repeat="item in allItems" 
ng-if="item.property != myItem.property">{{item.property}}</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why I can't use it using filter?

Comment: you're welcome. in this specific case i think you cannot use an inline filter because you have provided an entire expression, not a simple filter like for example {filter: myproperty}. I think the only way to do it is wrap the functionality in a method of the $scope and bind it to the filter like you did , filter:exceptCurrentItem   or use a simple ng-if.  cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please use jquery filter in js files.

```
$scope.allItems = $filter('filter')($scope.allItems , { property: !$scope.currentItem.property});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for a way to do it directly in the view.